# Не могу установить связь с WebSocket сервером [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, openssl, tornado

```
const socket = new WebSocket('wss://127.0.0.1:20003/', 'echo-protocol'); 
socket.onopen = function(event) {
  console.log('WebSocket connection established.');
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  const data = event.data; // Received data from the server

  // Handle the received data
};

// Send data to the server
function sendDataToServer(data) {
  socket.send(data);
}
```

Python код

```
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

class MyWebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        # Called when a new WebSocket connection is established
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        # Called when a new message is received from the client
        with open('messages.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(message + '\n')
            
    def on_close(self):
        # Called when the WebSocket connection is closed
        pass

app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/websocket', MyWebSocketHandler),
])
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.listen(20003, ssl_options={
        "certfile": r"C:\Users\Rakhat\GameTraining\cert.pem",
        "keyfile": r"C:\Users\Rakhat\GameTraining\key.pem",
    }) 
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Конверитировал сертификат в p12 формат и добавил в персональные сертификаты Chrome[image: certificate]

но терминал все также выдает

```
<tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer object at 0x000001994B139F10>
SSL Error on 664 ('127.0.0.1', 63715): [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN] sslv3 alert certificate unknown (_ssl.c:1002)
404 GET / (127.0.0.1) 1.15ms
```

Мне просто надо сделать так чтобы javascript "игра" постоянно отправляла данные о координатах (и т.п) и принимала действия на основе данных отправленных с python. Вебсокеты посоветовал GPT, но что то у меня совсем не получается все это настроить. Есть ли другие способы, или может быть решение проблемы с Websocket?